# using pseudo elements (after) in css using font family in font awsome 6 dosn't work

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

i am trying to make the div by css using after and i wrote the unicode in content and
the font family is "Font Awesome 6 Free" but nothing appear i dont know why please help
here is my html code
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- font awsome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
    <!-- end font awsome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <style>
        div::after{
            font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f015";
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
    
    <!-- font awsome -->
    <script src="js/all.min.js"></script>    
    <!-- end font awsome -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

i am trying to use the icon to make it appear in my page

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your html, check your font awsome css files

```css
div::after{
font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f015";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>

</div>
```